# How to prevent cascading filters. Or undo cascaded filter

Tags: css

I can't find a workaround for my problem. As you can see from my Codepen, I want do apply filter to parent element so that I can blur my image. The problem is the text child element gets blured too and when I try applying `filter:none` It doesn't change anything in text. Why is this happening ? How can I prevent it ? Thank you.

```css
.albums__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.albums__img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.albums__item:hover {
  filter: blur(2.5px);
}

.albums__item:hover>.albums__caption {
  filter: none;
}

.albums__caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.albums__caption--year {
  margin-top: 6rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.albums__caption {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.albums__item:hover>.albums__caption {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="albums__item albums__item--1">
  <img class="albums__img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DTVfQ4DX4AEYtmO.jpg" alt="Album image Koyu Antoloji">
  <figcaption class="albums__caption">
    <div class="albums__caption--name mb-md">Koyu Antoloji</div>
    <div class="albums__caption--year">2017</div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kgnugur/pen/OojNJZ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `filter` on the image...not the wrapper

```
.albums__item:hover img {
  filter: blur(2.5px);
}
```

```css
.albums__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.albums__img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.albums__item:hover img {
  filter: blur(2.5px);
}

.albums__item:hover>.albums__caption {
  filter: none;
}

.albums__caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.albums__caption--year {
  margin-top: 6rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.albums__caption {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.albums__item:hover>.albums__caption {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="albums__item albums__item--1">
  <img class="albums__img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DTVfQ4DX4AEYtmO.jpg" alt="Album image Koyu Antoloji">
  <figcaption class="albums__caption">
    <div class="albums__caption--name mb-md">Koyu Antoloji</div>
    <div class="albums__caption--year">2017</div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know ı asked an easy question for some, but why I down voted 2 times ? Is there a problem the way ı asked ?

Comment: You were probably downvoted initially because you did not put the code **in the question**. Codepen/JSFiddle etc are OK but they can go down and then your question would be of no value. I edited that for you.

Comment: I see, thank you for your time. I will add snippet next time for sure.